# How to make Django recognize JSON file in another directory

Tags: python, django, tweepy

I'm using a JSON file to store some credentials. I have a file with a function that opens that JSON file and uses the credentials to call the Twitter API using Tweepy. The file structure looks like this:

```
[search]/
├── [tweepi_api]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── get_tweets.py
│   ├── credentials.json
└── views.py
```

**init**.py looks like:

```
from .get_tweets import ApiAuth
```

Views.py looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from .tweepy_api import ApiAuth 

# Create your views here.
def search_bar(request):
    tweetObj = ApiAuth('IBM')
    tweet_text = tweetObj.get_tweets()

    return render(request, 'tweets.html', {'public_tweets': tweet_text})
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'
```

I'm not sure how to include this file in my project in a different way. Hope this is enough to answer my question. I can share more of the code if needed but my goals is not made the credentials visible when i upload this to Github and keep them as a json file on my machine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you include the code where you read in credentials.json?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show your `ApiAuth` code?

I think, error was occurred by `tweetObj = ApiAuth('IBM')`
In this code, we should find out that how to import credentials.json.

FYI, To import json file, you can use 'with statement` as follows.

```py
In [8]: with open("credentials.json", "r") as credentials_json:
   ...:     credentials = json.loads(credentials_json.read())
   ...:     for key, value in credentials.items():
   ...:         print(key, value)
   ...:

id example_id
password example_password
```